# Two bytes make one Uint16 everywhere, but not in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, byte

**Background**

I'm using `Three.JS` to create a heightmap viewer.

The data of the height-points of the height-map are `UInt16`, meaning they are two bytes.

I save the two bytes as `R` and `G` values in pixels of a `PNG` file and then send the picture to my `Three.JS` height-map viewer and manipulate the vertices `Y` position of a `PlaneGeometry`.

**Problem**

I can't figure out how to combine the two bytes together to a Javascript number.

Here's some code that doesn't seem to do what I need:

```
var result = (((byteA[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (byteB[1] & 0xFF));
```

**Question**

How do I turn two bytes into one number in Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"How do I turn two bytes into one number in Javascript?"*

Here's a quick working example code to combine two byte values into one result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>

var bytes = new Uint8Array(2); <!-- length for 2 items -->
bytes[0] = 0xAA;
bytes[1] = 0xBB;

var result = ( ( (bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF) );

alert("combined bytes have value : " + result);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives correct result of (hex `0xAABB` = decimal `43707`) :

```
combined bytes have value : 43707
```

If you want two separate bytearrays **bytesA** and **bytesB** then you'll have to create two separate `Uint8Array` (of total items/entries length) then fill each one with your values. Combine as usual.

There is also option to create `Uint16Array` if you later need to store `result` value in some bytes also (ie: not just as number). PS : You can read some useful info [about Typed Arrays here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).